# Formatação incorreta de string para decimal durante importação do Excel

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-excel, datagridview

Estou fazendo uma importação do excel para um dataGridView e a formatação do campo tipo Valor não traz a *virgula, ponto e casa decimais*, exemplo:

No `Excel` tá assim: **995.800,00 (certo)** e após a importação no `dataGrdiView` fica assim: **995800 (errado)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Trecho relevante do Código c#:**

```
FileInfo File = new FileInfo(txtArquivoOrigem.Text);
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(txtArquivoOrigem.Text));
ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

for (int i = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Row + 1; i <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row; i++)
{
    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
    for (int j = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Column; j <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Column; j++)
    {       
        if (j == 9)
        {
            decimal faturamento;
            bool resultado = decimal.TryParse(workSheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString(), out faturamento);
            if (resultado)
                cliente.Faturamento = Convert.ToDecimal(workSheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString());
        }       
    }      
    lCliente.Add(cliente);
}
```

**O valor como está no Excel:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Experimentei implementar a sugestão do [vik](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/17674/vik) , porém nem compila, retorna o seguinte erro: *Nenhuma sobre carga para o método "ToString" leva 1 argumentos.* : 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

```
cliente.Faturamento = Convert.ToDecimal(workSheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString());
```

Ao usar o TryParse, você já tem o valor na variavel `faturamento`... 
Se o `resultado` for `true`:

```
cliente.Faturamento = faturamento;
```

use depois .ToString("n") para apresentar no formato com separador de milhares e duas casas decimais.

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: experimentei implementar a sugestão, porém nem compila, retorna o seguinte erro:` Nenhuma sobre carga para o método "ToString" leva 1 argumentos.`, alterei o post e coloquei o print do erro.

Comment: nessa linha faça cliente.Faturamento = faturamento; e depois quando estiver a apresentar o resultado use então .ToString("n"), não pode usar esse formato de strings em objectos do tipo object... poste o codigo de como mostra/passa os dados para a datagridview

Comment: poderia fazer cliente.Faturamento = Convert.ToDecimal(faturamento.ToString("n")); mas apenas iria ficar com as duas casas decimais, para ficar também com o separador de milhares terá que formatar a var decimal à "saida".

Answer (score 0):

Talvez alterando a formatação na própria coluna (dei nome "*Faturamento*"):

```
MyDataGridView.Columns["Faturamento"].ValueType = typeof(decimal);
MyDataGridView.Columns["Faturamento"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,##0.00";
```